# ppgallery doesnot work in my php project

Tags: javascript, php

i know that this is a copy of questions about uncaught type error. But i didnt work this anyway

ERROR:Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ppGallery is not a function

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ppGallery is not a function(anonymous function) @ kerala-greenery.html:45c.extend.ready @ js.min.js:27L @ js.min.js:34

Code:

```
<base href="<?php  echo $this->get_base_url(); ?>" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/green.ico"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<link href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="ppgallery/css/dark-hive/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css"   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/date_input.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.date_input.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/functions_validation.js" >    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datemask.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="ppgallery/js/ppgallery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {

          if($){
                if($("#gallery")[0])
                    $('#gallery').ppGallery();
            }
        });

</script>


 <ul id="gallery">
<div class="gallery_head">Gallery</div><?php foreach ($gallery as $row) {     ?>
<!--href="app/public/uploads/<?php //echo $row->package_gallery_image; ?>"-->
<li><a href="images/malasya_gal_02.jpg"><img  src="app/public/uploads/<?php echo $row->package_gallery_image; ?>" HEIGHT="142" WIDTH="142" /></a></li>
<?php } ?> </ul>
```

`

Comment: I believe you have included jquery library twice,  its a common mistake.
js/js.min.js
js/jquery.min.js

Both corresponds to same library, Its a jquery conflict error. Try removing one of those it ll work. I guess

Comment: @tushar path is correct,
when i take theview page source and click in ppgallery.js ,it goesto that file

Comment: @lla tried it,but same error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ppGallery is not a function(anonymous function) @ kerala-greenery.html:45c.extend.ready @ js.min.js:27L @ js.min.js:34